# Table inner joined to itself with sum function in the having clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that returns incorrect results:

```
select sum(count(distinct stcr1.sfrstcr_pidm)) as sum_all
from saturn.sfrstcr stcr1
  inner join saturn.sfrstcr stcr2
    on stcr1.sfrstcr_pidm = stcr2.sfrstcr_pidm
where stcr1.sfrstcr_term_code = '200808'
  and stcr2.sfrstcr_term_code = '200908'
group by stcr1.sfrstcr_pidm
having sum(stcr1.sfrstcr_credit_hr) >= 12
```

I want the query to give me the number of `stcr1.sfrstcr_pidm` that have a total `stcr1.sfrstcr_credit_hr` of at least 12, and are present in `stcr2`. Though each record in `saturn.sfrstcr` is unique, `sfrstcr_pidm` can have any number of duplicate entries in its column.

However, the query takes the sum of `stcr1.sfrstcr_credit_hr` for every instance of `stcr2.sfrstcr_pidm`. So, for example, if the sum of `stcr1.sfrstcr_credit_hr` is actually 6, but there are two instances of  `stcr2.sfrstcr_pidm` joined to `stcr1.sfrstcr_pidm`, then the query gets a sum of 12, and incorrectly adds that `stcr1.sfrstcr_pidm` to the results. At least I think that's what happens.

If I replace

```
having sum(stcr1.sfrstcr_credit_hr) >= 12
```

with

```
having (select sum(stcr3.sfrstcr_credit_hr)
        from saturn.sfrstcr stcr3
        where stcr1.sfrstcr_pidm = stcr3.sfrstcr_pidm
          and stcr3.sfrstcr_term_code = '200808') >= 12
```

I get the correct results, but it seems like there should be a better way to do this that doesn't involve a subquery in the having clause. Any suggestions?

Comment: In your sub-query, you use stcr3.sfrstcr_term_code = '200808', whereas in the original query, stcr2.sfrstcr_term_code = '200908'. You would probably get the same results as the sub-query, if you use stcr2.sfrstcr_term_code = '200808. Alternatively, does the sub-query still work if you changed it to stcr3.sfrstcr_term_code = '200808'?

Comment: "there are two instances of  stcr2.sfrstcr_pidm joined to stcr1.sfrstcr_pidm" seems that it is the case for sfrstcr_term_code=200908 but not sfrstcr_term_code=200808

Comment: `stcr3.sfrstcr_term_code` has to match `stcr1.sfrstcr_term_code`, since I want the total `sfrstcr_credit_hr` for the `stcr1` term code. The `stcr2` term code differs because I am checking for `stcr1.sfrstcr_pidm` in 200808 that are also in 200908.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want the query to give me the number of stcr1.sfrstcr_pidm that have a total stcr1.sfrstcr_credit_hr of at least 12, and are present in stcr2."

If I'm not missing some nuance to the question, this would seem to be a fairly direct approach:

```
select count(distinct sfrstcr_pidm) 
from 
  (
    select sfrstcr_pidm
    from   saturn.sfrstcr
    where  sfrstcr_term_code = '200808'
           and sfrstcr_pidm in 
               (select sfrstcr_pidm
                from   saturn.sfrstcr
                where  sfrstcr_term_code = '200809')
    group by sfrstcr_pidm
    having sum(sfrstcr_credit_hr) >= 12
  )
```

Comment: This does produce the same results. Thanks for providing an alternative method.